# Convert to datetime from Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime

i know there are a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Here is my oracle date:

```
string testdate= "2014-01-07 15:00:00.0000000";
```

And here is how I tried to convert to datetime:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(testdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This throws a format exception. Any ideas?

My quick test also throws the string not valid datetime exception. Quick test:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(testdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: What does the exception say? Does it provide any futher details?

Comment: Are you assigning it a to a variable DateTime result = {your parse goes here}

Comment: string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Comment: yes, in the app. as a test I just did this: Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(testdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString());

Comment: You need more `f`s...  4 more to be exact.

Comment: Some Oracle feature... I use Convert.ToDateTime([value retrieved from the db]);

Answer (score 3):

I'd *start* by trying to avoid getting it as a string in the first place. Make sure you're using the appropriate data type in Oracle, and you should be able to call `GetDateTime` on the appropriate `DataReader` (or whatever you're using).

If you *must* parse it as text, then you need to specify a format which matches the value - so use 7 `f`s instead of 3, given that your value has ".0000000" at the end.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(testdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But again, I'd *strongly* urge you to avoid having to deal with the value as text at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `ParseExact` at all? Reqular `Parse` seems to work.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-07 15:00:00.0000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Prints out 2014-01-07T15:00:00.0000000
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("o"));
```